# How to change cell format on ImportHTML Function

Tags: google-sheets, importhtml

I've used the ImportHTML function to scrape play-by-play information from Basketball Reference.

I am using a Vlookup to create a rating system based on time, point different, and several other factors.

I realized the TIME vlookup isn't reading correctly, but the formula is exactly how it should be (I've tested it, and it works fine when I type in the info manually).  It only doesn't work on the time that is coming from my ImportHTML.

I can't get the format to match - I've tried every format option on both my vlookup & the data, and tried forcing it with the TEXT function (might of not done that correctly).

I'm at an absolute stand-still at this point -- has anyone experienced anything similar?

Other ways to force a format change on imported data? or another way to correctly pull the values from a range of times? I've tried the Lookup function as well.

Demo Link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gUqjDiy1KA1nFE52F9hmYluJC2O5EwPp1zT2uuBYjwY/edit?usp=sharing

For Reference:

=VLOOKUP(H11,$J$2:$L$6,3,TRUE)

[image: upper lower bounds]

[image: importfunction]

Comment: It is because your time cells are not formed as numbers. There are different remedies for that. But instead of trying to guess which is the best one, please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Thanks @marikamitsos - I couldn't seem to get the cells to switch format no matter what I tried - I'm sure there is a way to do so though.  I updated my question to include a demo link; really appreciate it - this is driving me nuts!

Comment: Sorry, I am kind of lost in your sheet. Please, in a new tab, write only some data (not 500 rows), the vlookup formula you try and the expected results.

Comment: Hey @marikamitsos my apologies - I tried to throw as much info on there as possible, but it is cleaner now & should be easier to follow.  The issue is on the "Rating" tab; "Raw Bball Info" is only there to show you how I'm importing the times (Column A)

Comment: Sorry but you still have 500+ rows and still cannot understand which is the *"My issue is getting this vlookup to work..."* or where/what are your expected results.

Comment: Really sorry @marikamitsos - I think it is better now; I put an example of the correct result vs. the incorrect result (what I'm getting now) at the bottom of the "Rating" tab -- I think that should help but let me know if there is anything more specific that would clear things up. Appreciate the help

Comment: You still have given no clue whatsoever on how you come up with all those  *"0:10 0:59 0.176
1:00 4:59 0.132
5:00 8:59 0.088
0.375 0.5 0.044"*  numbers. Anyway. Your issue is that your `B` column is text and not numbers. Please check my added formula on your sheet to get an idea of how that text can be converted to numbers. Time-out :/

Comment: My apologies @marikamitsos - they are just lower and upper time boundaries; depending on which range the time of the specific imported cell falls in, that third column is the result I want to pull.  I am trying to develop a rating formula of my own, this is just one piece.

I appreciate the help - I'm still having trouble & it seems you're really great at this.  Should I switch the format of my time boundaries & values? I tried moving it to automatic rather than plain text, but the result is still incorrect. Any thoughts? Much appreciated!